# Malus Law in Michelson Morley experiment

Tags: visible-light, polarization, interferometry

My book of physics (I don't quote it here, since it is in Catalan) says 
that in the 1887 Michelson - Morley experiment, after getting the transversal and longitudinal phase shifts, they claim that the number of fringer observed will belong to the number of times that both phase shifts contains 2 pi because that is the phase two maximums  repeat.
My question is: why is here said that waves should form maximums? Because as I understand it, the expected result was to obtain a destructive interference whose phase shift could be jsed to determine Earth's velocity. If they were expecting a destructive interference, shouldn't the book use the phase two **minimums** repeat?

Comment: The first question we need you to answer is "Do you understand the principle of super-position in general?" That is can you explain what happens when waves from two sources intersect one another ?

Comment: I only have a general idea. I know that two waves form a destructive imterference if they are not in phase and a constructive one if they are in phase. But I don't have a specific knowledge of waves.

Comment: Are you sure your textbook does not explain this? d is the phase difference between the waves in the 2 arms of the interferometer.