# Maximums and minimums

Tags: visible-light, interferometry

My book of physics (I won't uote it here, since it is in Catalan) says that in the 1887 Michelson - Morley experiment, after getting the transversal and longitudinal phase shifts, they claim that the number of fringer observed will belong to the number of times that both phase shifts contains 2 pi because that is the phase two maximums repeat. My question is: why is here said that waves should form maximums? Because as I understand it, the expected result was to obtain a destructive interference whose phase shift could be used to determine Earth's velocity. If they were expecting a destructive interference, shouldn't the book use the phase two minimums repeat instead of using the interval when twho maximums do?

Comment: Please do not [delete and repost closed questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274911/50583), but edit them instead.